# UIView popup and textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

hi i have problem with textfields and setAnimationDuration when i hit the text it comes like this

https://vid.me/DU50

and this is the code

```
-(IBAction)open:(id)sender{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 63, 320, 568);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: @JakubVano as you see in video the textfield menu its come from up not like normal textfield. how can i fix it

Comment: Where's your call to `commitAnimations`? And why are you using the old, outdate animation methods? Use the new, modern block based animation methods.

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIView`. Look at the section labeled "Animating Views with Block Objects".

Comment: @rmaddy now i see finally fixed it with [UIVew commitAnimation ]